# In Cloud Spanner, how do I see connections to my instance

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

In most other databases, there is usually a way to tell what's connected to your database, and what they are doing (e.g., "Show processlist" in MySQL).

Is there a way to tell who's connected to your database or Instance in Cloud Spanner?

Answer (score 2):

There is a ListSession API call that you can access via API or CLI that gives you a list of active sessions:

https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/sessions